# Curve, circle, sphere

Tags: calculus, geometry

I need to prove that a naturally parametrized curve $a$ lying on the unit sphere is a "big" circle iff 
$a=-a''$ (second derivative of $a$)
Any ideas? I know that $k=1$ and torsion $= 0$. What is enough to know that it is a circle, but how can I know that it is a big circle? Also, I'm not sure about other direction of equivalence.
Help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, these things are called "great" circles, not "big" circles.

If you have shown that $k=1$, then you've done most of the work. If $k=1$, then the radius of curvature is $1/k =1$, so the circle has radius 1, so it's a "great" circle.

In the other direction: if you have a great circle, it's radius is $1$. So, write down parametric equations and differentiate to show $a''=a$.

Comment: Sorry about my mistake, English is not my first language, so I am not familiar with all of the terms. And I do have another question: am I suppose to write that usual parametrization of the circle (cost, sint) and differentiate that?

Comment: No apology required. You need to write parametric equations for the circle that give it unit speed. I suppose that's what "naturally" parameterized means. So, it will involve $\sin$ and $\cos$, probably with some scaling to get unit speed.